# debconf error messages from apt-get install line in Dockerfile

Tags: apt, dpkg, docker, debconf

I am learning about Dockerfile and had not worked with curl before.

When running [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/popestepheng/meteor-production-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile) .  The terminal output gives:

[image]

And then:

[image]
Googleing around tells me that there was an interactive dialog which could not be handled.

The last command I saw in the terminal output was
`Step 7 : RUN apt-get install curl -y   && ...` which starts on line 15 to line 39

How am I suppose to deal with this? Thanks

**edit**
[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22466739/5047454) in the link in the comments give a pointer to [ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html), after reading the man page, I am not sure how to incorporate this solution in my case. Any help? thx

**edit 2**
The accepted answer suggests to use `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. How do I incorporate this in my Dcokerfile? thx

Comment: please copy the text and post it here as text instead of screenshots

Comment: does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466255/is-it-possibe-to-answer-dialog-questions-when-installing-under-docker

Comment: @lesmana I tried to copy the text but it will be not formatted and lose end of line, looks bad and difficult to read.

Comment: SE has a [formatting markup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), do read that, do read the man page, and understand that telling someone off for giving you RTFM will only produce more people telling you to RTFM.  Do RTFM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. ignore the messages as they seem to be non-fatal.
2. replace every `RUN apt-get install ...` with `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...`
3. add `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` after the `FROM ...` line at the top.

Using option 3 the first few lines of you linked dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
MAINTAINER Stephen Pope, spope@projectricochet.com
```

read more about `ARG`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466255/is-it-possibe-to-answer-dialog-questions-when-installing-under-docker